# How can create signed apk with terminal?

Tags: android, signed-apk

Creating the signed apk with terminal

I am developing the android application and I want to create singed apk with terminal cause of I have CI/CD pipeline and I want to use firebase. I want to create apk with CI pipeline later i want to send the apk with firebase. How can i do this ?.

I tried the ./gradlew assembleRelease command. it created the unsinged apk. I tried the install in my phone but I took error. it is "invalid package" . How can i create singed apk with terminal

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/build/building-cmdline#sign_cmdline) will help you.

Comment: @tomerpacific thanks man.it is working for creating the singed apk.